# It keeps telling me "Class 'GameScene' has no initializers"

Tags: swift, class

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var movingGround: JTMovingGround!
    var hero: JTHero

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
       backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159.0/255.0, green: 281.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
       movingGround = JTMovingGround(size: CGSizeMake(view.frame.width, 20))
        movingGround.position = CGPointMake(0, view.frame.size.height/2)
        addChild(movingGround)

        hero = JTHero()
        hero.position = CGPointMake(70, movingGround.position.y + movingGround.frame.size.height/2 + hero.frame.height/2)
        addChild(hero)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        movingGround.start()
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
    }
}
```

could someone tell me what went wrong?? thanks

Comment: You need to accept an answer if it solved your problem

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because you have a non-optional property that  doesn't have a default value.

```
var hero: JTHero
```

Is non-optional but it also has no value.

So, you can either make it optional by doing

```
var hero: JTHero?
```

Or you can create an init method and set the value in there.

Or create a default value...

```
var hero = JTHero()
```

There are many ways to do the latter.

Answer (score 1):

> Classes and structures *must* set all of their stored properties to an appropriate initial value by the time an instance of that class or structure is created. Stored properties cannot be left in an indeterminate state.
>
> You can set an initial value for a stored property within an initializer, or by assigning a default property value as part of the property’s definition.

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. *The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease)* iBooks. https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l

Your `GameScene` class is not setting any initializers for its stored properties and does not define an `init()` method, and this is causing the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is fixed now